# Difficulty in learning calculus 3 years after one has learned calculus 2?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, soft-question

Academically speaking, I'm a late bloomer.  Long story short, I was a bad kid, teachers told me I wasn't good at math and I believed them.  Years later, as an almost 30 year old man, I started going back to school about 3 years ago.  I taught myself Algebra and placed directly into a pre-calculus class when I started at my community college.

So far I've gotten an A in every math class I've taken up through Calculus 2.

I started out majoring in Computer/Electrical Engineering, but I just switched to Computer Science purely because of scheduling (online class availabilty).  While I'm getting my degree in Computer Science for my career I'm in a dilemma with regards to where my passion really is.

All my recent studies in math has absolutely made me fall in love with mathematics.  However, my Computer Science degree only requires two more math classes: Linear Algebra and Discrete Math (which seem like they are easier than Calculus 3 and DE).  I absolutely HATE not taking Calculus 3 and Differential Equations, but should I really feel this way?

If my long term life goal after working all my hard years is to retire and teach mathematics, is it a realistic goal to pick up where I left off with Calculus 2, perhaps years later, and learn Calculus 3 and everything else that is needed to become a math teacher?

Comment: You should definitely revise calculus to make sure that you're not forgetting the basic concepts, but with a bit of effort, you will definitely be able to pick up Calc III.

Comment: Do they let you take Calc 3 and Diff. Equations even though your CS curriculum doesn't require it? If so, I suggest you take them. If you taught yourself Algebra and aced Calc 2, then I think those classes won't be overly hard for you. And you might find them usefull even for a career in computer science, especially if you ever end up doing numerical simulations or something like that...

Comment: @fgp is it OK to take Linear Algebra before Calculus 3?

Comment: @inquisitor Yeah, I'd even strongly recommend doing so. I don't know what your calculus 3 class teaches exactly, but if you do multi-dimensional differentation and integration, then linear algebra will help tremendously.

Comment: @inquisitor And BTW, nice to see that at least some CS students are actually into math! As someone who studies both and has worked as a software engineer, I feel that way too many CS students see math as a burden, instead of as a very valueable tool. Kudos!

Comment: @fgp thanks for the kudos!  I started programming before the math classes and it has made me a much better programmer and thinker altogether.

Comment: @inquisitor "goal after working all my hard years is to retire and teach mathematics" This sounds a bit naive. Where do you want to teach mathematics without work the easy way?

Comment: @phira I didn't mean to make it sound like teaching mathematics would be an easy goal.  I really meant that I want to retire and do something I'm really passionate about and love.  I've been in the computer industry for over 10 years and have a stable career so jumping out and doing math at this point in my life is unrealistic for me.  This is why it's a long term goal.